# NSIS RequestExecutionLevel on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, nsis

Well, my installer is working good from several years under Windows XP and Windows 7 with RequestExecutionLevel admin. Installer pops up with UAC dialog each time on Windows 7.

Recently on Windows 8.1, I need to manually choose 'Run as administrator' from context menu to work it properly. Though for both of the situations (i.e. Running installer by double click or Running by right click and choose Run as) UAC pop up is showing.

The problem is, installer install my product properly but its not getting started until I reinstall it with manual Run as admin.

I'm not getting any clues whats wrong. Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: If the UAC elevation dialog comes up every time, why do you think it is a RequestExecutionLevel issue? What do you mean by your product not getting started? Is it a service? Something you start on the finish page?

Comment: @Anders: Well its a 32bit windows application. It has some ocx, dll which gets called on exe startup and some of the ocx calling failing if the installer is not getting installed by Right click and 'Run as Admin'. After a few research on web I was thinking whether I need to include '!packhdr "$%TEMP%\MySetup.exe" 'header.cmd'' in my installer script for windows 8 support.

Comment: @Anders: After a bit more findings I found the ocx registration is not being done properply if I run the installer without manual Run as admin. I'm registering the ocx using RegDLL. Is there a issue with RegDLL and Windows8 with admin rights?

Comment: If you run it normally, does Process Explorer say that the process is High or Medium integrity? (You have to enable this column)

Comment: @Anders: Have to check. BTW whats that for?

Comment: >= High means UAC elevated process